# Dependencies compatibility with Java 7

Tags: maven-dependency

I am upgrading my struts Application from oracle java 6 to 7.

To do that i am upgrading my dependencies version in pom.xml file.

I need to know about which version of the dependencies compatible with java 7. Here I mentioned the group-id and artifact-id of the dependencies:

```
org.glassfish.hk2 - hk2-api
org.glassfish.hk2 - hk2-utils
org.codehaus.jackson - jackson-core-asl
org.codehaus.jackson - jackson-jaxrs
org.codehaus.jackson - jackson-mapper-asl
org.codehaus.jackson - jackson-xc
org.glassfish.hk2.external - javax.inject
javax.xml.bind - jaxb-api
junit - junit
javax.validation - validation-api
commons-codec - commons-codec
commons-httpclient - commons-httpclient
org.codehaus.xfire - xfire-aegis
org.codehaus.xfire - xfire-annotations
org.codehaus.xfire - xfire-core
org.codehaus.xfire - xfire-java5
org.codehaus.xfire - xfire-jaxb2
aopalliance - aopalliance
jcifs - jcifs
```

This is my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
<artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0-b14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
<artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0-b14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>1.5.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
<version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
<version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
<version>2.2.0-b14</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
 <version>4.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
<version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
<version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
<artifactId>xfire-aegis</artifactId>
<version>1.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
<artifactId>xfire-annotations</artifactId>
<version>1.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
<artifactId>xfire-core</artifactId>
<version>1.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
<artifactId>xfire-java5</artifactId>
<version>1.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.xfire</groupId>
<artifactId>xfire-jaxb2</artifactId>
<version>1.2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
<artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>jcifs</groupId>
<artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
<version>0.7.0b12</version>
</dependency>
```

Please advise me on this.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: But then: why on earth do you upgrade to Java 7? You understand that Java 7 is long dead, too? If at all, go for Java 8, or bite the bullet and hop to Java 11 instead. But 7, that is a waste of time.